# Interaction with ETH smartcontract using BSC wallet

Tags: tokens

wrong chain, while interacting with smart contract

took me a while to get into this point, but i suspect that, when I wanted to delegate erc20 tokens for staking, I have by accident used wallet created in meta, but imported to trustwallet from private key, but on BSC network.

I wanted to delegate Matic tokens, but it was in january 2021, before their mainnet launch so it was a bit complicated, and bip44 where not respected everywhere (i think)

long story short, instead of being staked,  tokens were transfered to a wallet which I have no access to, cant find it using Coleman bip39 with my seed phrase even when changing derivation paths, and there is no sign of them when I log into delegator portal.

Of course I can be wrong with this, but if not, Is there any chance to recover them ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140559/discussion-on-question-by-mike-danxxx-interaction-with-eth-smartcontract-using-b).

Answer (score 0):

If you have transferred token to the wrong address you can't get them back